# Retrieve records on matching a field in any 2 tables out of 4 tables

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have four tables with same fields. Now I want to join these tables in such a way that I retrieve records only if there is a match between any **two** tables on a field(like name).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible to have duplicates in any of the tables?

Comment: Plz provide ur table structure. Ur expected output. So that we can help u out.

Comment: Yes duplication is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would return all the `name` values that appear in more than one table:

```
select
   name
from
    (select distinct
       name
    from table1
    union all
    select distinct
       name
    from table2
    union all
    select distinct
       name
    from table3
    union all
    select distinct
       name
    from table4) temp
group by name
having count(*) > 1;
```

Check out the [interactive example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef7959/2).

Comment: Thanks for your reply and getting my question. I request you what if I have different field name  like in table1_name in table1 and table2_name in table2 etc?

Comment: Then you can just use those fieldnames in the union block.

Comment: The first name or alias in the union block is used for the entire block. Supposing `table1` has a column called `peculiarName`, you could just alias that column `peculiarName as name` and that'll apply to the other tables in the union block below.